# How to get *all* classes in Pharo?

Tags: reflection, smalltalk, pharo

Conundrum... tried `Smalltalk allClasses` and `TBehaviour` in `Kernel-Traits`, among others, seems to be missing from the list. Interestingly enough it is a `Trait` not a `Class`...? there seem to be corresponding `allTraits` *and* `allBehaviors`.

Any others we should know about when trying to get everything? Or is there some other method to get everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute:

```
Smalltalk allClassesAndTraits.
```

Comment: I gave it a go. I had something along the lines of "Smalltalk globals allBehaviors"... interestingly enough yours returns 5801 objects, mine returns 11602, exactly twice. Hmmmm

Comment: @unmircea half of them are metaclasses (because each class has a metaclass)... you can tell by their name `Something class`

Comment: I see. Got it!!

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I thought that reflection was described in some Pharo book but I don't see it in any, so can't direct you for further reading.*

#### Classes are Objects

You can always use reflection on Pharo objects, which might give you a bit more insight into what you are actually looking for.

Any class is also an object, an any object understands message `allSubclasses` (or `withAllSubclasses`) that will give you... the subclasses.

`Object willAllSubclasses`

Note that the above will give you also the "class-side" classes (which are metaclass instances for each class), because they are objects too; so

```
Smalltalk allClasses asSet =¹ (ProtoObject withAllSubclasses \ Class allSubclasses) asSet
"or"
Smalltalk allClasses asSet = (ProtoObject withAllSubclasses \ Metaclass allInstances) asSet
```

#### Traits are not Classes

`Trait` is a class, but `TBehavior` is not; instead it is an *instance* of `Trait`.

So you can say

```
Trait allSubclasses. "an OrderedCollection()"
Trait allInstances. "{... TBehavior. TClass. ...}"
```

---

¹`SMarkCompilerTargetClass` is some special snowflake.

Comment: In my mind I see them all as "groups" of methods, the fact that they also provide these methods with access to variables is of no consequence to me. What I really want to get at is all method implementations, and because each method implementation is under one such "group" (call it a class, trait or other) means I need a list of all of these "groups". Unless there is another way to get at all the method implementations in the system and?!

Comment: @unmircea well you were asking about classes, now you are asking about implementations. If you want to get implementors of selectors `#sum`, you can just ask. `#sum implementors`

Comment: It is fine classes is what I was after, and after that all methods of each class. Managed to fix it!